# Phonegap ondevice ready

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap application with several html files, and for each html file I have js.file.
In each js file I'm adding an eventListener like this:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{ 
   alert('HI'); 
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false);
```

Now when the app starts I'm checking if the device is ready and alert some string (for test).

But when I change to another html file, it doesn't work, it works just on index.html file.
It seems that it doesn't fire the event listener for the other pages, why?

**Edit:**
Ok so as it said in the comments below, device ready in only called one time.

So I tried to call to a javascript function with the onload event:

```
 <head> 
     <script src = "js\file.js type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
 </head>

<body onload = "onLoad()">
</body>
```

in the js file there is a function :

```
function onLoad()
{
     alert('HI');
}
```

but when I move to this page, it doesn't alert.

I tried also in this way:

```
 <head>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
            {
                alert('HI');
            })
    </script>
  </head>
```

and still.. nothing..

Comment: onDeviceReady executed only first time when application launched.

Comment: yes I know but before that I tried to call to a js function from the onLoad event, and it didn't work either, so I tried to test if this will help to solve the problem, but it didn't

Comment: I linked my js file to the html file, but it didn't call the function.. it's wierd

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. First, how are you directing to other pages? 
If you are doing it like this

```
<a href="otherpage.html"></a>
```

sometimes the .js files don't work correctly.

When you add a click event to buttons and direct to other page like this;

```
setTimeOut( function() { document.location = "otherpage.html";},50);
```

it works.

This is how I solved my problem and I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Im using jquery mobile, so when the user click on the button , the code was "$.mobile.changePage('otherPage.html');

Comment: You can use javascript functions in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

So after many attempts to get things work, I didn't manage to "fire" the onload event of the other html pages.

It seems that JQM support only in one html.file with multiple divs, which each div is acting like a page, using the attribute data-role set to page.

I don't know why it didn't fire the event for the other html files, because I added all the necessary js files to those html files.

If you can find  any other solution, I will be thankful.. but meanwhile I think this is the only solution, and in my opinion its kind of bad thing, because if you have a lot of pages for your app, it will be hard to maintain it... and that's why I tried to separate into a different pages (html files)

Comment: you have single page app(only one html with multiple page) or multiple html app.

Comment: right now, as i said, I have just one html file with multiple divs which each div is acting like a page (another screen)

Comment: In single page the DOM loads only at first time..No need to call the ondeviceready each and every time..just one time it is enough to acces  al cordova features.

Comment: I know that, but the question was for multiple html files.. not one file. When i had multiple pages the problem was as described on the question above, and i changed it to one file

Comment: in multiple file you need to specify in body `onload` function. Then only the deviceready event fire. If you are using JQuery mobile then include ondeviceready in `pageshow` event.